# VS2010: The annoying "missing web components" dialog after installing SP1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Last year after I installed SP1 on Visual Studio 2010, I started getting this annoying popup every time I open any of my websites (they're all based on Umbraco).

[image: Missing web components dialog]

I do not need those components, so I don't want to install them, but there was [no way to disable this dialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vssetup/thread/425e2370-b57d-42f9-b348-bc8d50d4ad05) back then.

It's been a year, I wonder if anyone has found a way of getting rid of this dialog?